# Finding The Derivative Of an Inverse

Tags: derivatives, inverse, inverse-function-theorem

I know the general formula is $$\frac{1}{f\prime(f^{-1}(x))}$$
would anyone know what the formula would be for the second derivative? is it f double prime in the denominator or do you take the entire equation and apply the quotient rule?

Comment: For the particular function you care about, can you compute $(f^{-1})'(x)$? Assuming you can, you then merely need to take the derivative of that. Want more help? Show us that you've made an effort. And while you're at it, go ahead and type in the question you really want to answer rather than pasting it as an image: images aren't searchable.

Comment: The site wouldn't let me post the picture even though I have before; I had no other option then to post it as a link. I have made an effort and I am just confused about this particular part not how to solve the entire question.

Comment: "is it f double prime in the denominator or do you take the entire equation and apply the quotient rule? "  ... well, it *is* a quotient, isn't it? So yes.  The double derivative is simple the derivative of the derivative.  And the derivative is a quotient.  So, yes.

Comment: My problem wasn't with you posting or linking the picture, it was with not typing the formula itself (which would make it searchable).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate the relation $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ twice using the Chain Rule, and you can solve for $(f^{-1})''(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $f^{-1}(x)=g(x)$ then $g$ satisfies $g(f(x))=x$. Now differentiate this twice
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(x)g'(f(x))=1 \\
f''(x)g'(f(x))+(f'(x))^2g''(f(x))=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
To finish calculate $f'$ and $f''$ and substitute $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

"I know the general formula is "

$\frac{1}{f\prime(f^{-1}(x))}$

That is correct.  (Because $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ so by chain rule $[f(f^{-1}(x))]' = f'(f^{-1}(x))*{f^{-1}}'(x) = 1$.

"is it f double prime in the denominator or do you take the entire equation and apply the quotient rule?"

Yes.

$h(x) = \frac{1}{f\prime(f^{-1}(x))}$ so $h'(x) = -\frac {[f\prime(f^{-1}(x))]'}{[f\prime(f^{-1}(x))]^2}=-\frac {f''(f^{-1}(x))*(f^{-1}(x))}{[f\prime(f^{-1}(x))]^2}$

$=-\frac {\frac{f''(f^{-1}(x))}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}}{[f\prime(f^{-1}(x))]^2}= -\frac{f''(f^{-1}(x))}{[f\prime(f^{-1}(x))]^3}$

But the real question is, how can you evaluate $f'(f^{-1}(x))$ without determining what $f^{-1}(x)$ is.  And if you *can* determine what $f^{-1}(x)$ is in the first place, why do all this indirect oblique derivation when we could have just expressed $f^{-1}(x)$ and derived the derivative directly?